# How can I get an exclusive tailset of a SortedSet?

Tags: java, sortedset

I want to get an exclusive tail set of a SortedSet.  The shortest method I can come up with is:

```
private void exclusiveTailSet(SortedSet<String> s, String start) {
    System.out.println(s); // [Five, Four, One, Six, Start, Three, Two]
    SortedSet<String> t = s.tailSet(start);
    System.out.println(t); // [Start, Three, Two]
    Iterator<String> i = t.iterator();
    i.next();
    SortedSet<String> u = t.tailSet(i.next());
    System.out.println(u); // [Three, Two]
}
```

The [javadoc for tailSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html#tailSet%28java.lang.Object%29) suggests asking for the subset starting from the next element in the domain (i.e. for Strings calling `s.tailSet(start+"\0");`), however I'm actually working with objects such that it would be much more of an overhead to create it.

**What is an efficient and clean general method to create an exclusive tail set?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any better method than the one you describe.

You can make it slightly more general though, by making it a generic method:

```
public static <T> SortedSet<T> exclusiveTailSet(SortedSet<T> ts, T elem) {
    Iterator<T> iter = ts.tailSet(elem).iterator();
    iter.next();
    return ts.tailSet(iter.next());
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll stop trying to find a better method then.  The generic method is good, and I didn't notice that there's no need to define a new set `t`.

Comment: I also added a try catch block for `NoSuchElementException` to return an empty TreeSet in that case.

Comment: Yup. That case struck my mind too... Good solution... Actually, you should probably return *the* empty tailset in that case, (to be consistent with the other implementations the set returned should be backed by the given set).

Comment: I don't think you can return *the* empty tailset as tailSet is inclusive!  I think you come back to the problem I had in the first place :-)

Answer (score 5):

NavigableSet interface is a subimplementation of the SortedSet. If i understand your question correctly you can use NavigableSet's tailset method, which has the ability to be either inclusive or exclusive, depending on what boolean you provide.

```
 NavigableSet<E>    tailSet(E fromElement, boolean inclusive)
      Returns a view of the portion of this set whose elements are greater than (or    equal     to, if inclusive is true) fromElement.
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html

Comment: SortedSet implements a NavigableSet interface.? SortedSet is super interface of NavSet, isn't it?

Comment: @Mechkov, so if he has a `SortedSet` as input, he can't assume it's a `NavigableSet`, i.e., your answer doesn't solve his problem.

Comment: @aioobe Thats correct. I assumed we had control of the input. NavigableSet is a SortedSet after all, but the opposite is not always true. I might have assumed too much. Good point though!

Answer (score 0):

is this helpful?
(I just copy and paste your codes in question, and did some change:

```
private void exclusiveTailSet(SortedSet<String> s, String start) {

    SortedSet<String> t = s.tailSet(start);


    t.remove(t.first());


}
```

and if you have "start" element as parameter, it would also be

```
t.remove(start) ;
```

Comment: Note that this changes `s` as well. Presumably not a desired behavior. You could make a copy of the tailset, and remove an element from the copy, but that would change the original approach from logarithmic to linear, so it's a far worse approach.

Answer (score -1):

Guava version 11:

```
   SortedSet exclusiveTailSet = Sets.filter(eSortedSet, Ranges.greaterThan(start));
```

**p.s.** There is also a **hack** for SortedSet in case you couldn't use NavigableSet. The solution is to add for the search pattern a special symbol (start+"\0"). And this addition symbol will change the hashCode and thus the default tailset implementation of a SortedSet will work fine:

```
 SortedSet<String> t = s.tailSet(start+"\0");
```

It will be an equivalent of java.util.TreeSet#tailSet(E fromElement, boolean *inclusive*) with **false** value in a second parameter.

---

God bless that the last com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSortedSet (since version 12)   has an implementation of NavigableSet also.

Comment: Hi - thanks for your suggestion of Guava, I will have to have a look at that.  I mentioned that I didn't want to use the start+"\0" method in my question - it was not really suitable, as this was a simplification of my real scenario which was working with objects. Creating an object that was the next in the sort order seemed like quite a large overhead.